# RegEx in VBA: Removing line returns from data field in XML file

Tags: regex, vba

For someone who knows Regular Expressions, this is probably pretty trivial.

I have several XML files that I need to import, but because some of the fields were originally user-entered, they can have line returns within the data. I am using VBA because the database I am importing into is Access, so it's what is immediately handy.

Sample line in the XML:

```
  <dbXML comments="This is line 1.
This is line 2." />
```

I tried a regular brute-force import, replace and export to replace line returns with ;, but that also caught all the line returns at the end of each XML line.  Which was bad.

I have looked at a couple of similar questions on this site, with a reference document for RegEx open to figure out what they say, but can't quite make the jump from reading RegEx to writing it.

I can give the following definitions for the problem:

- The only line returns I want to replace with a ; are between both <> and ""
- The "" is always within the <>
- so it looks something like <......".....\n...."....>

For the example I gave at the top, I want it to end up like:

```
  <dbXML comments="This is line 1.;This is line 2." />
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can't you just remove the line breaks upon reading/parsing the XML file? i.e. first, get the text of the comment tag, and then remove line breaks from that as needed.

Comment: I am trying to do a bulk import in Access tables, and the line returns are breaking it.  The person before me had a script that he ran that removed them, but it no longer works on my computer (outdated due to upgrades, I think), so I am trying to build a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit old fashioned, so I'll do this without RegEx.

```
Dim xmlString As String
Dim thisChar As String
Dim i As Long
Dim insideTag As Boolean

' Make an example xml string
xmlString = "<dbXML comments=""This is line 1." _
    & vbCrLf & "This is line 2."" />"
xmlString = xmlString & vbCrLf & xmlString

Debug.Print "Before:"
Debug.Print xmlString

insideTag = False 'Assume we are NOT inside a tag to start with.
For i = 1 To Len(xmlString) 'March through the string char by char
    thisChar = Mid(xmlString, i, 1)
    If Not insideTag Then
        If thisChar = "<" Then
            'We're entering a tag.
            insideTag = True
        Else
            'Do nothing. Leave line breaks alone.
        End If
    Else
        'We're inside a tag.
        If thisChar = ">" Then
            'We've reached the end of this tag
            insideTag = False
        ElseIf thisChar = vbCr Or thisChar = vbLf Then
            'Remove line breaks.
            Mid(xmlString, i, 1) = ";"
        End If
    End If
Next i

Debug.Print "After:"
Debug.Print xmlString
```

I'm sure that there exists a RegEx that will do the same thing more succinctly. 
However it would take me ages to figure it out, compared to the 2 minutes it took me to write out the above code, which works.

Comment: Shoot.  I'm trying to get a project done on a deadline, not compose a work of art. ;)  I'll use whatever works.  Let me plug this in and add the file manipulation commands, and if it all works, I'll come back and click the check.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The code does work.  The data is still not importing, so *apparently* I have more problems than I suspected.  (mutter, grumble)  Thank you again for the assist!